# Linechart of highchart is giving me a blank page

Tags: javascript, linechart

I use the simple linechart example from [highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com/), but all I see is a blank page. What is wrong with the code? My jquery script is above the 3rd party script and all I did was following the instructions.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
          <script>
        $(function () {
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    title: {
                        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: '°C'
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Tokyo',
                        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                    }, {
                        name: 'New York',
                        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                    }, {
                        name: 'Berlin',
                        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                    }, {
                        name: 'London',
                        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                    }]
                });
            }); 
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
              <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>    
        </body>
        </html>
```

The javascript console says: **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined** on line 17.

Comment: That looks OK to me. Have you tried in different browsers ? Which file is the error in (line 17) ?

Comment: Yeah I tried it in Mozilla Firefox.. Nothing happened. And line 17 is the line with: $('#container').highcharts({ @SteveP

Comment: You can check in firebug whether jquery.min.js is getting loaded.

Comment: Okay this is very confusing now.. It works in Firefox now but still not in CHrome. I Need it to work in Chrome because our whole presentation is in Chrome @SteveP

Comment: In chrome, press F12 and check to make sure everything is being loaded in the correct order.

Comment: What is F12 on the Mac?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts